# How to have multiple tags in same image in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I currently have the following part of my docker-compose file:

```
uima_taln_concept:
    image: uima_taln_concept
    build:
      context: ./wrappers/concept_extraction
    ports:
      - "5556:8000"
    volumes:
      - /datasets/taln/concept_extractor/20200124/models:/app/models
    environment:
      - LANGUAGE=en
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - FLASK_DEBUG=False
    command: ["gunicorn", "--reload", "-b 0.0.0.0:8000", "-t 300", "server:app"]
```

I want to create two tags, `uima_taln_concept:flask` and `uima_taln_concept:fastapi` . The only difference between these two images is the first line of the Dockerfile, that will say

`FROM uima_flask` and `FROM uima_fastapi` respectively. Since I will repeat this for many images, is there a way to do this that isn't simply copy-pasting the entire description of `uima_taln_concept` and change a few things? I was thinking of something like being able to asociate a tag with a specific Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables and set them in the environment before using the image:

```
uima_taln_concept:
    image: uima_taln_concept:${IMAGE_TAG}
    build:
...
...
```

Then when you call docker-compose run:

```
~# IMAGE_TAG=fastapi docker-compose up -d
```